# Working with Memcached and mysqli (php on GAE)

Tags: php, google-app-engine, mysqli, cron, memcached

I am working on scalable solution for my code .

what i am doing right now is serving ads and keeping the impression and clicks on 
memcached and via cron pulling the clicks and impression every hour .

```
what i am doing right now is saving array on single key (rand key) and

saving the key on key name - 'keys' by append
```

than inside the cron i am doing a loop and saving all the keys inside the mysqli.

how can i improve this components ?

Comment: Sorry, this question is far too broad to be answered here. Please read about what questions to ask here and how. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you don't care about undercounting, storing data in memcache and expecting it to be there some time later isn't a viable approach. Memcache is a shared resource. Items in GAE memcache have have a highly variable lifetime depending on how other apps are treating memcache. It's a shared resource, best treated as a short-term, great-if-it's-there cache.